# Change value of attributes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a C# application to copy a XML structure in to a new one with help of XSLT transforms using XslCompiledTransform. I'm a total beginner on XSLT and now I'm a bit stuck on my XSLT-code. 
I want this XSLT Transform to change the search path for all elements of a specific type with a matching pattern in an attribute (from Linux file-path to Windows)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:from="http://example.com/schema/FieldSinks/v1.xsd" xmlns:sqlite="http://example.com/schema/SQLiteFieldSink/v1.xsd" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions">

 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="winsrc">c:\data\</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="linuxsrc">/var/persistent/data/</xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="from:FieldSinkRoot//sqlite:SQLiteFieldSink/@*">
    <xsl:for-each select="//sqlite:SQLiteFieldSink/@*[contains(.,'/var/persistent/data/')]">

      <xsl:variable name="str" select='.' />
      <xsl:variable name="str2" select="substring-before($str, $linuxsrc)" />
      <xsl:variable name="str3" select="substring-after($str, $linuxsrc)" />
      <xsl:variable name="str4" select="concat($str2,$winsrc)" />
      <xsl:variable name="str5" select="concat($str4,$str3)" />
      <xsl:attribute name="connectionString"><xsl:value-of select="$str5 "/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FieldSinkRoot id="FieldSinksRoot" xmlns="http://example.com/schema/FieldSinks/v1.xsd">
    <SQLiteFieldSink 
      id="HourValues"  
      idleTimeout="5000" 
      connectionString="Data Source=/var/persistent/data/fsSQLiteHour.db;Version=3;"  
      warningSearchLevel="2000" 
      warningOnZeroResults="false" 
      deleteOldFields="true" 
      keepFieldsInMonth="24" 
      xmlns="http://example.com/schema/SQLiteFieldSink/v1.xsd" >
    </SQLiteFieldSink>
    <SQLiteFieldSink 
      id="MinuteValues"  
      idleTimeout="5000"
      connectionString="Data Source=/var/persistent/data/fsSQLiteMinute.db;Version=3;"  
      warningSearchLevel="2000" 
      warningOnZeroResults="false" 
      deleteOldFields="true" 
      keepFieldsInMonth="24"
      xmlns="http://example.com/schema/SQLiteFieldSink/v1.xsd" >
    </SQLiteFieldSink>
    <LocalDatabaseFieldSink 
      id="Localhost" 
      idleTimeout="5000" 
      warningSearchLevel="1000" 
      warningOnZeroResults="true" 
      xmlns="http://example.com/schema/LocalDatabaseFieldSink/v1.xsd" />
</FieldSinkRoot>
```

I get this output file (new XML-file), which is wrong because it looks like its using the same string for the search path and the filename is wrong in the end. Both elements gets the same file-ending **fsSQLiteMinute.db** instead of **fsSQLiteHour.db**

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FieldSinkRoot id="FieldSinksRoot" xmlns="http://example.com/schema/FieldSinks/v1.xsd">
  <SQLiteFieldSink 
    connectionString="Data Source=c:\data\fsSQLiteMinute.db;Version=3;" 
    xmlns="http://example.com/schema/SQLiteFieldSink/v1.xsd" />
  <SQLiteFieldSink 
    connectionString="Data Source=c:\data\fsSQLiteMinute.db;Version=3;" 
    xmlns="http://example.com/schema/SQLiteFieldSink/v1.xsd" />
  <LocalDatabaseFieldSink 
    id="Localhost" 
    idleTimeout="5000" 
    warningSearchLevel="1000" 
    warningOnZeroResults="true" 
    xmlns="http://example.com/schema/LocalDatabaseFieldSink/v1.xsd" />
</FieldSinkRoot>
```

Comment: FYI `XslCompiledTransform` doesn't support XSLT 2.0. You're not actually using any 2.0 features, so you should change the version to 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- You are matching *all* attributes on SQLiteFieldSink elements and replacing them *all* with `connectionString` attributes
- You are selecting attributes using an absolute path (in your `for-each`) which doesn't take into account which parent they actually belong to.

You need to make use of relative paths to locate nodes. I think the following is what you were actually going for:

```
<xsl:template match="sqlite:SQLiteFieldSink/@*[contains(.,'/var/persistent/data/')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="{ name() }">
    <xsl:variable name="before" select="substring-before(., $linuxsrc)" />
    <xsl:variable name="after" select="substring-after(., $linuxsrc)" />

    <xsl:value-of select="concat($before, $winsrc, $after)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

When that template is replaced in your XSLT and it is run against your input,the result is:

```
<FieldSinkRoot id="FieldSinksRoot" xmlns="http://example.com/schema/FieldSinks/v1.xsd">
  <SQLiteFieldSink 
    id="HourValues" 
    idleTimeout="5000" 
    connectionString="Data Source=c:\data\fsSQLiteHour.db;Version=3;" 
    warningSearchLevel="2000" 
    warningOnZeroResults="false" 
    deleteOldFields="true" 
    keepFieldsInMonth="24" 
    xmlns="http://example.com/schema/SQLiteFieldSink/v1.xsd" />
  <SQLiteFieldSink 
    id="MinuteValues" 
    idleTimeout="5000" 
    connectionString="Data Source=c:\data\fsSQLiteMinute.db;Version=3;" 
    warningSearchLevel="2000" 
     warningOnZeroResults="false" 
    deleteOldFields="true"
    keepFieldsInMonth="24" 
    xmlns="http://example.com/schema/SQLiteFieldSink/v1.xsd" />
  <LocalDatabaseFieldSink 
    id="Localhost" 
    idleTimeout="5000" 
    warningSearchLevel="1000" 
    warningOnZeroResults="true" 
    xmlns="http://example.com/schema/LocalDatabaseFieldSink/v1.xsd" />
</FieldSinkRoot>
```